# python function cache a mutable result

Tags: python-3.x, caching, mutable

Is there a way to cache a mutable result and prevent the cache being modified after function call?

```
from functools import lru_cache
import pandas as pd

@lru_cache
def myfun(x):
    return pd.Series(index = [1,2,3], data = [10,20,30])

A = myfun(4)
A[2] = 1 # this changed my cached result

B = myfun(4)
print(B) # wrong return
```

Normally, `myfun` is a time-consuming data reader from db and returns a large pandas df. It tends to be called multiple times in a script. (Please assume I don't have full control of how people use the function return afterwards)